# How to format algebric code for readability

Tags: code-structure, code-standards

I have a fairly complex-looking (about 50 chars when typed out) equation that is all basic algebra (`*`, `/`, `+`, `-`, `^`). How would I best style it for readability?

Condensed, it looks difficult to read and impossible to understand how I got there, so I'm thinking about putting an expanded form with explanation as comments above the code. This, however, still leaves the "code" bit unintelligible.

Any pointers/suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Before suggesting, can you please share the statement you are talking about? - probably a dummy one

Comment: @Abhishek for example `((x^2-2)/(y-2))+(y*4)`. This is a simple example, but understand how it can expand

Comment: I would write this expression as
```
(pow(x,2) - 2) / (y-2))
+ (y*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things I follow while using long mathematical expressions:

1. Use of descriptive name for the variables.
2. Break the expressions and calculate in smaller chunks. (group based on the operation or logic)
3. Use brackets and break the line into multiple lines
4. look for the inbuilt function available in the programming language used. like (avg, sum, pow, exp, log). They increase readability.
5. lastly, move only the calculation within a function.

for example

```js
totalIncome = totalSvcSale
            + totalProductSale
            + interestIncome
totalExpenses = toalTransportation
                + Marketing
profit = totalIncome - totalExpenses
```

Edit: To answer the above expression discussed in the comment

```js
(pow(x,2) - 2) / (y-2))
+ (y*4)
```